# How to change text in a XML element?

Tags: xml, powershell

Let's say I have the following XML element:

```
<test> 1000 </test>
```

I want to change it to:

```
<test > 500 </test>
```

Using PowerShell how would I do this.

I know how to make the xml object with PowerShell and make a node variable to access a certain node within the XML. I just don't know the exact command(s) to replace the text inside the node.

Answer (score 9):

As with everything PowerShell this can be done multiple ways.
If you had an element such as `<test name="frank">Some Text</test>` you could change it by doing:

```
[xml]$xml = '<test name="frank">Some Text</test>'
$xml.test.InnerText = "Some Other Text"
```

If, however, your element is simple as described in the question (`<test>1000</test>`) you need to be a little careful.

```
[xml]$xml = "<test>1000</test>"
$elements = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//test")
$elements[0].'#text' = "500"
```

The reason for this is that PowerShell will return a string for `$xml.test` and setting this string doesn't update the XmlDocument.

Comment: I'd prefer `SelectSingleNode('//test')` over `GetElementsByTagName('test')`.

Comment: Of course.  There are multiple ways to select the element, but the key is to not use `$xml.test` if the element has only text as powershell will parse this as a string and appears to not update the XMLElement when the string is modified.
I'll update my answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a certain node you can set `node.InnerText = 500`.